# ZDecompressStream() causes memory leak

Tags: delphi, compression, delphi-xe2, zlib

I've been using `ZLib` functions to compress/uncompress streams in memory. In case when I try to uncompress invalid stream, it leaks memory. The following code would leak memory:

```
uses
  Winapi.Windows, System.Classes, System.ZLib;

function DecompressStream(const AStream: TMemoryStream): Boolean;
var
  ostream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  ostream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    AStream.Position := 0;

    // ISSUE: Memory leak happening here
    try
      ZDecompressStream(AStream, ostream);
    except
      Exit(FALSE);
    end;

    AStream.Clear;
    ostream.Position := 0;
    AStream.CopyFrom(ostream, ostream.Size);
    result := TRUE;
  finally
    ostream.Free;
  end;
end;

var
  s: TMemoryStream;

begin
  ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := TRUE;

  s := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    DecompressStream(s);
  finally
    s.Free;
  end;
end.
```

I try to decompress empty `TMemoryStream` here and at the end of execution it shows that memory leak happened. Testing on Delphi XE2.

Any ideas how to prevent this leak to happen, because in real world there would be a chance for my application to try to decompress invalid stream and leak the memory there.

QC: http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=120329 - claimed fixed starting with XE6

Comment: A good SSCCE but you should also post the leak message.

Comment: Mayeb you could use "Mark and sweep" approach ? Intercept GetMem/FreeMem/ReallocMem before decompression and track all the allocated resources. Then de-hook them after decompression attempts and free all the allocated memory.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers it's generic leak message - "An unexpected memory leak has occured. The sizes of unexpected leaked medium and large blocks are: 7212"

Comment: @MarkoPaunovic - If I recall correctly, you should be able to see what object/string/... leaked and where it got allocated. That should give you some pointers as to wether you should be concerned about it or if it's a none issue. I can't test this *(no Delphi)* and the complete message *might* help.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers only if he will download and install full FastMM4 (http://fastmm.sf.net) distribution and set its debugging options for most detailed report.

Comment: I figured out that the problem is indeed internally in `ZDecompressStream()`, thanks to @Arioch'The. It was calling `InflateInit()` at beginning, but `InflateEnd()` was never called because it was raising exception before that, terminating function, and inflate functions weren't wrapped in `try..finally` block.

Comment: Well, did you managed to work-around that by explicitly freeing the leaked blocks ?

Comment: @Arioch 'The - good to know, tx.

Comment: I just wrote my own, slightly modified, `ZDecompressStream()` implementation. Luckily, almost all methods in `ZLib` unit are exposed, so it just worked outside of unit.

Comment: i have a copy of XE4 sources and there it seems the same. Did not saw XE5 though.  Can you register your bug with demo project on http://QC.embarcadero.com ?

Comment: Maybe you could patch stock `ZDecompressStream` so it would always redirect to your fixed implementation. Just for the case some other unit already uses stock `ZDecompressStream` or you or your co-workers would put units to uses in wrong order, etc. Just to remove the possibility of broken `ZDecompressStream` ever get executed

Comment: I can't post the bug since I can't login for some weird reason, despite I have account there. But feel free to do it instead me if you want to. Simply wrapping `inflateInit()`/`inflateEnd()` in `try..finally` would fix the bug.

Comment: Also this bug seems persistent in other `ZLib` unit functions that do compression/decompression too.

Comment: You may re-implement those functions in a proper way and patch them  like it was done in https://github.com/the-Arioch/XE2fixes
Since we can hardly expect any fixed from EMBT themselves (even their QC stuff are volunteers) we only have to do it ourselves :-) // Try running **c:\RAD Studio\9.0\QualityCentral\qualitycentral.exe** - to me it did log in

Comment: A fix is mentioned here: [Fix List for Embarcadero Delphi XE3 and C++Builder XE3](http://edn.embarcadero.com/de/article/42606)

Comment: Being lazy person i perhaps would make `TInterfacedObject` wrapper over inflateInit/inflateEnd rather than keep inserting those try-finally sections time and again :-)

Comment: @Bummi diff'ing ZLib.pas of XE2 and XE4 i see that those functions were not touched. EMBT changed things in TZStream (Int64 offsets and seeks, dynamic array rather than fixed-size buffer, etc), remamed PAnsiChar type and introduced few DeflateXXX functions, written using try-finally.But `ZDecompressStream` they did not touch. So they must have fixed something unrelated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug in the Delphi RTL code. The implementation of `ZDecompressStream` raises exceptions and then fails to perform tidy up. Let's look at the code:

```
procedure ZDecompressStream(inStream, outStream: TStream);
const
  bufferSize = 32768;
var
  zstream: TZStreamRec;
  zresult: Integer;
  inBuffer: TBytes;
  outBuffer: TBytes;
  inSize: Integer;
  outSize: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(inBuffer, BufferSize);
  SetLength(outBuffer, BufferSize);
  FillChar(zstream, SizeOf(TZStreamRec), 0);

  ZCompressCheck(InflateInit(zstream));   <--- performs heap allocation

  inSize := inStream.Read(inBuffer, bufferSize);

  while inSize > 0 do
  begin
    zstream.next_in := @inBuffer[0];
    zstream.avail_in := inSize;

    repeat
      zstream.next_out := @outBuffer[0];
      zstream.avail_out := bufferSize;

      ZCompressCheck(inflate(zstream, Z_NO_FLUSH));

      // outSize := zstream.next_out - outBuffer;
      outSize := bufferSize - zstream.avail_out;

      outStream.Write(outBuffer, outSize);
    until (zstream.avail_in = 0) and (zstream.avail_out > 0);

    inSize := inStream.Read(inBuffer, bufferSize);
  end;

  repeat
    zstream.next_out := @outBuffer[0];
    zstream.avail_out := bufferSize;

    zresult := ZCompressCheck(inflate(zstream, Z_FINISH));

    // outSize := zstream.next_out - outBuffer;
    outSize := bufferSize - zstream.avail_out;

    outStream.Write(outBuffer, outSize);
  until (zresult = Z_STREAM_END) and (zstream.avail_out > 0);

  ZCompressCheck(inflateEnd(zstream));   <--- tidy up, frees heap allocation
end;
```

I've taken this from my XE3, but I believe that it is essentially the same in all versions. I've highlighted the problem. The call to `inflateInit` allocates memory off the heap. It needs to be paired with a call to `inflateEnd`. Because `ZCompressCheck` raises exceptions in the face of errors, the call to `inflateEnd` never happens. And hence the code leaks.

The other calls to `inflateInit` and `inflateEnd` in that unit are correctly protected with try/finally. It just appears to be the use in this function that is erroneous.

My recommendation is that you replace the `Zlib` unit with a version that is implemented correctly.

Comment: David, QC is already posted, see the edits to the question :-)

Comment: @Arioch'The Thanks for that. Good for you for taking the time to submit it. FWIW, I didn't open up the comments, there were so many. I just looked at the code and spotted immediately the flaw. Only later did I read the comments. Anyway, it's better that the question has an answer rather than the details being buried in comments.

Comment: Well, i think it would more fair to give topicstarter few days, so he would post his own answer and accept it. But he agrees to stamping your answer - that is okay too.

Comment: @Arioch'The Usually they move on because their problem is solved. And it's left to us to tidy up the questions. And as I said, I didn't read the comments. I just supplied an answer to a question that appeared to be in need of one.